# How to write a Test class for after Delete Event

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

Can anyone help me to write a Test class for below Trigger

```
trigger DeleteCRonContactDeletion on Contact (after delete) {

    set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact objCon:Trigger.old){
        contactIds.add(objcon.Id);
    }
    if(trigger.isBefore){
        if(trigger.isDelete){
            for(Contact c:Trigger.old){
                Contact_Relationship__c objCR = new Contact_Relationship__c();
                objCR = [SELECT id FROM Contact_Relationship__c WHERE id In:contactIds];
                delete objCR;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: does your trigger even work? You set it's only event to be `after delete`, but looks like your logic will only fire if the trigger is fired at **before delete**. Also, do not put queries inside loops. And your query will fail if it returns 0 or more than 1 result.

Comment: Can you please post your code whatever you have tried so far

Answer (score 5):

Let's review you code line per line and what will happen.

```
trigger DeleteCRonContactDeletion on Contact (after delete) {
```

trigger declaration. Note, that it will only fire in an **after delete** event

```
set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact objCon:Trigger.old){
    contactIds.add(objcon.Id);
}
```

Nothing really wrong here, this will be executed without a problem. Although, you can also just use `Trigger.old` in the query.

```
if(trigger.isBefore){
```

code execution will only enter this `if`, if and only if you are in a **before** trigger. Read: your execution will never get inside. Therefore, the following will NEVER be executed:

```
if(trigger.isDelete){
    for(Contact c:Trigger.old){
        Contact_Relationship__c objCR = new Contact_Relationship__c();
        objCR = [SELECT id FROM Contact_Relationship__c WHERE id In:contactIds];
        delete objCR;
    }
}
```

---

Then let's look at where the logic happens:

```
for(Contact c:Trigger.old){
    Contact_Relationship__c objCR = new Contact_Relationship__c();
    objCR = [SELECT id FROM Contact_Relationship__c WHERE id In:contactIds];
    delete objCR;
}
```

why do you even need this loop? You do not use that `Contact c` anywhere. Also, I would guess that you want to use some lookup field instead of `Id`. Ids are unique in Salesforce, so your SOQL will not retrieve a single row. Why not just re-write this as:

```
delete [SELECT Id FROM Contact_Relationship__c WHERE Contact__c IN :Trigger.old];
```

Just change the `Contact__c` to the lookup field that connects to contact. I assume that this is what you want.

And if it is a Master-Detail(which can easily be the case, seeing that you want help with test class and not trigger fixing = you think that trigger works): all child records will be automatically deleted if you delete the parent. So you can just delete this trigger and enjoy the fact that you do not need a single line of test code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is available for `after delete` but your code has a condition for `Trigger.isBefore`, so the below snippet of your code will never be covered.

```
if(trigger.isBefore){
        if(trigger.isDelete){
            for(Contact c:Trigger.old){
                Contact_Relationship__c objCR = new Contact_Relationship__c();
                objCR = [SELECT id FROM Contact_Relationship__c WHERE id In:contactIds];
                delete objCR;
            }
        }
    }
```

So you will have to make this trigger available for `before delete` also.

Again, the code in the above snippet is seems wrong.

In the where clause of the SOQL query, you are comparing Child_Relationship__c ID with contact Id which is invalid.

So please rethink the design you have and validate that with your requirement.

Comment: Santanu, did you notice that he is not querying contacts but rather Contact_Relationship__c.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The query still holds invalid though. He is matching Contact_Relationship__c ID with Contact Ids.